# How can be the variables change in other file? batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batching

So here is what I need , I have two files , the first one is this:
1)

```
set idVendor=3edd
```

In the second file is this:
2)

```
   write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable 0
write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idVendor %idVendor%
write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idProduct 4EE2
write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions mtp,adb
write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/iManufacturer ${ro.product.manufacturer}
write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/iProduct ${ro.product.model}
write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/iSerial ${ro.serialno}
```

So I want to replace %idVendor% with 3edd , but in the other file

NOTE:
the other file is not a bat file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I was looking for was this

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=%~1"
set "replace=%~2"
set "textfile=Input.txt"
set "newfile=Output.txt"
call repl.bat "%search%" "%replace%" L < "%textfile%" >"%newfile%"
del "%textfile%"
rename "%newfile%" "%textfile%"
```

So thanks to myself I think lol :D

Comment: What is your source for `repl.bat`?

Comment: It appears that `jrepl.bat` is the successor to `repl.bat`. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about retaining spaces in the result, you could simply use `cmd` to interpret the replacement.

```
C:>type file1.bat
SET "idVendor=3edd"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s IN (`TYPE file2.txt`) DO (
    CMD /C ECHO %%s
)
```